# API - xml response formatting

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Hello I'm creating an `api` to get id and name as `Xml`  like this
Response Formats

```
  <posts>
  <post>
  <account_id> </account_id>
  <name> </name>
  </post>
  </posts>
```

You can find below what models I define

```
Partial Public Class PostsPost

    Private postField As Posts

    Public Property Post() As Posts
        Get
            Return Me.postField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.postField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


  Partial Public Class Posts



    Private account_idField As String

    Private nameField As String




    Public Property Account_id() As String
        Get
            Return Me.account_idField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.account_idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.nameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property


 End Class
```

Then below the source code that I'm using

```
    Try myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = xxx.xxx.x.yy;port=1234;Database=test;User ID=test;Password=test123;"
            If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                myConnection.Open()
            End If

            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
            Dim mysqlCmd As New MySqlCommand()
            mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            mysqlCmd.CommandText = "Select account_id,name from xx where  account_id Like ?p1 and xylike ?p2 "
            mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p1", xxx)
            mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p2", yyy)
            mysqlCmd.Connection = myConnection
            reader = mysqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                Dim smtSub As Posts = Nothing
                While reader.Read()
                    smtSub = New Posts()
                    smtSub.Post.Account_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0))
                    smtSub.Post.Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()

                End While
                myConnection.Close()
  return smtSub
```

End If

The problem that the response is without the `<post>` like the example below

```
   <posts>
    <account_id> </account_id>
    <name> </name>
     </posts>
```

Comment: Can you check that you've posted correctly please: your target XML doesn't close the `<amount>` tag; the `If reader.HasRows` is missing the `End If`; and you return `smtSub` even though this is reinitialised inside  your `While` loop. Thanks

Comment: i just write the <amount> by mistake ; End if present in VS project but here i forget to put it - the problem that it just return
 <posts>
    <account_id> </account_id>
    <name> </name>
     </posts> 
note like this  <posts>
  <post>
  <account_id> </account_id>
  <name> </name>
  </post>
  </posts>

Answer (score 0):

Change sql query may be your solution. Below query add a post node in your xml.
Try this

```
 mysqlCmd.CommandText = "select xml_tag('Posts','Post',null,null) from xx where  account_id Like ?p1 and xylike ?p2 "
```

Comment: thanks jaihind i get this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML PATH('post') as post' at line 1

Comment: @user3619254 I made a change in sql query as you are using MySQL